# How can I change the value of a constructor key after it has been created?

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a simple constructor exercise and I need to change a value after the initial creation of the constructor. When I run it the cat is still not making its noise after I changed its value to true.

### Challenge parameters

- The constructor function will take in two parameters, `raining` and `noise`. These will be passed into the keys as their value.
- Create a third key that will be a function called `makeNoise()`. The function checks if the `raining` key's value is `true`. If it is, it will log the value of the key's `noise` in the console.

Bonus

- How can we make the cat make noise? In other words, how can we change the value of `raining` for the `cat` object after it has been created?

```
function Animal(raining, noise) {
    this.raining = raining,
    this.noise = noise;

    this.makeNoise = function(){
        if(this.raining)
        console.log(noise)
    }
}
// Creates `dog` and `cat` objects with `raining` and `noise` properties
let dog = new Animal(true, 'Woof!');
let cat = new Animal(false, 'Meow!');

// Calls the `makeNoise()` methods on the `dog` and `cat` objects
dog.makeNoise();
cat.makeNoise();

// BONUS CODE HERE
cat.raining= true;
```

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: sorry, first question. I edited the question to include that...

Comment: Did you forget calling `cat.makeNoise();` after changing `cat.raining`? The code works fine, otherwise.

Comment: The directions are to change that value and get a proper log (both animals making noise) without making the call again.

Comment: @DaveToth You really should specify _all the relevant_ requirements of the challenge _in the question itself_. How do we now know what we can change and what we can’t change?

Comment: The challenge doesn’t say anything about not calling the method again.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `makeNoise()` after setting the `raining` property to `true`. When you call `makeNoise()` before, the `raining` property is `false` (since JS is (mostly) executed sequentially), so nothing is logged.

```js
function Animal(raining, noise) {
  this.raining = raining,
    this.noise = noise;

  this.makeNoise = function() {
    if (this.raining)
      console.log(noise)
  }
}
// Creates `dog` and `cat` objects with `raining` and `noise` properties
let dog = new Animal(true, 'Woof!');
let cat = new Animal(false, 'Meow!');

// Calls the `makeNoise()` methods on the `dog` and `cat` objects
dog.makeNoise();
cat.makeNoise();

// BONUS CODE HERE
cat.raining = true;

cat.makeNoise();
```

Comment: OK, I had it in my head that I could change the value without calling again and that it was implied that I could. Just learned about constructors/prototypes etc and thought I was missing something.